# How do I get value from parent row

Tags: oracle, hierarchy

I have two tables.

One contains a hierarchical structure of topics and another table that contains optional configuration of that topic, that controls it's visibility in several contexts (one column for each).

Let's call these tables *Topic* and *Conf* respectively. 
The relationship between *Topic* and *Conf* tables is `1:0..1`, (a particular *topic* might have a row for it's respective *conf* or not, in which case it inherits conf from it's parent topic)

**Question:** How can I create a query that will list all visibility options for all topics (including those inherited from parent conf)?

I do have an idea how to create a hierarchical query of topics using `START WITH ...` and `CONNECT BY ...` clauses, but I do not know how to promote values from *parent* row.

Answer (score 1):

May be this will help.

```
with topicdet as
(select t.topic_id as topic,c.conf as configuration,t.parent_topic_id as parenttopic from topic t left outer join config c on t.topic_id=c.topic_id)
select a.topic, NVL(a.configuration,CONNECT_BY_ROOT configuration) as conf from topicdet a
connect by nocycle prior a.topic=a.parenttopic;
```

if you dont want to use hierarchical query then

```
with topicdet as
(select t.topic_id as topic,c.conf as configuration,t.parent_topic_id as parenttopic from topic t left outer join config c on t.topic_id=c.topic_id)
select a.topic,case when a.configuration is null then (select b.configuration from topicdet b where b.parenttopic=a.topic) else a.configuration end as config from topicdet a
```